# How to find maximum of a function that has a logarithmic variable?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How can I find the maximum of a function that is of the form 
$$f(x)= 4\dfrac {\log(x-3)}{x-4}+6\dfrac {\log(8–0.5x)}{14-x}$$

I understand that I have to take first derivative and equate it to zero, to find critical points, and then calculate second derivative. But the derivative is too complex to solve.

[first derivative of f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrdzx.png)

Comment: As written, the function has no maximum, seems like: [graph](https://i.imgur.com/bV9ymre.png). Also, here's [a reference for MathJax](https://is.gd/BbUegD) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misintepreted the text of your homework (form 2 instead of form 1 as given in my first comment ?)

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not the minimum of $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.
@Jean Marie: It is of the second form ( log is only in the numerator). I am sure that I haven't misinterpreted.
@

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and information provided in them. I will make sure to use LaTex or MathJax next time.

@ Claude Leibovici: I am sure, the question is to find the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not exist because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow3^+}f(x)=+\infty.$$